# Opencv naming image captures

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to capture images from my `cv2.imshow` using the `cv2.imwrite` method, however I am getting an error when I try to use a function to constantly change the name of my capture. Does anybody know how to do this because I am getting an error.

My Code:

```py
def imgcap():
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    last_name = 9
    def imgnames(last_name):
        last_name = last_name + 1
        return last_name

    while True:
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        cv2.imwrite('capture {last_name}', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    
    vid.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

imgcap()
```

My Error:

```
    cv2.imwrite('capture {last_name}', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-oduouqig\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:682: error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'cv::imwrite_'

[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-oduouqig\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to pick the extension for your new file? Please try one of the lines below!

```
    cv2.imwrite('capture{last_name}.png', frame)
    cv2.imwrite('capture{last_name}.jpg', frame)
```